# How to extract field content in powershell

Tags: powershell, field, extract

- History: I'm making a Powershell script in order to create user from a defined table containing list of users and put them in a defined OrganizationalUnit.
- Problem: At the end of the script, I'd like to have a report in order to list whether or not there is one or many user account disabled amoung newly created account

In my script, I have to input a password for each user, but I may enter a password that won't meet the password policy defined in Active Directory; in this case, the account will be created but disabled.

To proceed, I tried :

```
dsquery user "ou=sp,dc=mydomain,dc=local" -disabled
```

and it print me this :

```
"CN=user1,OU=SP,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
"CN=user2,OU=SP,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
"CN=user3,OU=SP,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
```

- My goal : I'd like to extract in a variable the values in "CN" field in order to compare them to the inital user table in my script.

  ```
  dsquery user "dc=mydomain,dc=local" -disabled | where-object {$_.CN -ne $null}
  ```

or

```
dsquery user "dc=mydomain,dc=local" -disabled | where-object {$_.Common-Name -ne $null}
```

But it didn't help (doesn't work). How can I proceed please?

Comment: Do you not have access to AD cmdlets for this thing? If not have you looked up parsing distinguishedNames? dsquery does not return PSObjects either so you wouldnt be able to treat them as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not tested - just "from my mind"

```
$csvData = Import-Csv 'UserList.csv' -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
$userList = dsquery user "ou=sp,dc=mydomain,dc=local" -disabled
$listOfDisabledAccounts = @()
foreach ($user in $userList)
{
    if ($csvData.Name -contains (($user -split ',')[0] -replace 'CN=',''))
    {
        $listOfDisabledAccounts += $csvData.Name
    }
}

$listOfDisabledAccounts
```

Answer (score 0):

`dsquery` is not a PowerShell cmdlet, but an executable. This means that it is not going to return PowerShell objects to the pipeline. Kongstead's method works off of the knowing that it returns string output. By manipulating the string using `split` and `replace` you can get the output into something usable for your purposes. The other two methods to get this information would be to use the  the AD module (from [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) on desktop OSs) and ADSI methods from .Net. Both of these would return data that would be directly usable.

The AD cmdlets would be the easiest. To get all the disabled accounts would look something like this:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -SearchBase "dc=mydomain,dc=local"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses PowerShell's match function to parse the CN field, similar to the answer from Kongsted. It should help you achieve what you are looking for, if using AD cmdlets is not an option.

```
#This is the output from your current query, from the question, it appears to be an array.
$output = ("CN=user1,OU=SP,DC=mydomain,DC=local","CN=user2,OU=SP,DC=mydomain,DC=local","CN=user3,OU=SP,DC=mydomain,DC=local") 

$disabledAccs = @()
foreach ($line in $output) {
    #match everything after CN= up to the next comma
    if([string]$line -match "CN=([^,]*)"){
        $disabledAccs += , $Matches[1]
    }
}
```